# git rev-list not working inside github action

Tags: git, github, github-actions

I have a github action that is triggered when a release is created.

The goal is to:

- Find the tag on which the release was based
- Find the previous tag on that branch

So far, I have this:

```
CURRENT_TAG=${{ github.event.release.tag_name }}
PENULTIMATE_TAG=$(git describe --exact-match --tags `git rev-list --tags --max-count=1 --skip=1`)
```

These are then echoed out for testing. The first works correctly, but the second always returns empty. I have tried the exact same command locally, and it returns the second most recent tag, as expected.

I have no idea why it wouldn't work in a github action. For the sake of debugging, I removed the `git describe` component, confirming that it is in fact git `rev-list` that is returning nothing.

Comment: Hint: shallow clone. Increase its depth or disable shallow clone completely.

Comment: @phd Ah, found it, thank you!

Answer (score 12):

Need to fetch all history by passing the fetch-depth option:

```
 - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      with:
        fetch-depth: 0
```

Comment: It's really helped!.

Comment: lol lifesaver! i spent hours trying to debug this xD