# Github actions - How to get a build number that starts from 1 in each branch

Tags: github, github-actions, cicd

Suppose I have these branches:

- main
- feature1
- feature2

In my github actions I need to know what is number of times I have pushed into a branch or I have manually triggered the actions on that branch

**With `${{ github.run_attempt }}`:**
each time I push I get the number `1`. I only get a new number if I manually rerun the job

**with `${{ github.run_number }}`:**

each time I push to this repository in any branch it is incremented.

so suppose I push to the main or feature1 or feature2 branches, it is added to this number

But if I manually trigger the pipeline, it is not added to it

---

I need a variable that if I push to any branch for the first gives me the number `1` and if I push again/or trigger manually it adds to it.

so suppose I push 2 times into the feature1 branch and run it manually once and then push again, it gives me the number 4 in the next push or manual trigger, independent of what has happened on the other branches or their pipelines.

I need this number because on my docker registry my path is like this:

**docker-reg-host/project-name/branch-name:the-number-from-above**

the-number-from-above is the number of times the pipeline is triggered manually or by pushing, in this specific branch not other branches

I want to add a new tag each time that is this number

---

I can make the requirement simpler and request a variable that returns run_number of a specific branch

then I am going to  choose this strategy

**docker-reg-host/project-name/branch-name:branch_run_number-run_attempt**

But at least I need to know how many times I have pushed to this specific branch

Comment: You can count the number of commits and then add `github.run_attempt` to it. See this thread for counting commits: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11657295/count-the-number-of-commits-on-a-git-branch.

Comment: I am not counting the commits - I am counting the pushes

Comment: @azeem this is related to your comment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63284060/git-rev-list-not-working-inside-github-action

Comment: `I need this number because on my docker registry my path is like this:

docker-reg-host/project-name/branch-name:the-number-from-above` why? Normally that suffix is a version tag

Comment: no, it is not the case. I want each branch tag to be a meaningful number not a big number related to all branches

Comment: That doesn’t answer the question of why, what does this mean `not a big number related to all branches`? Please zoom out and describe the problem you are trying to solve (in detail)

Answer (score 3):

GitHub doesn't capture a run number per branch. GitHub also doesn't expose the number of pushes to a branch in an easy accessible way.

It's up to you to come up with a number.

- One way would be for your workflow to tag the commit. That way you can count the tags on the branch. And thus get to your number.
- Another way would be to query the docker registry for the versions that have been pushed there. With a bit of powershell or another scripting language you could then find the highest version on your branch and add one to it before pushing the new container.
- Yet another way would be to use the current date&time as a version on the branch.
- Or to simply do what everyone has suggested so far, to count the number of commits since the last tag/branch and optionally add the attempt number to it.

[Here is an action that uses the "tag" strategy and automatically pushes a new tag to the repo](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/build-tag-number). You can pass in a prefix, in your case the branch name (`ref_name`), to generate a new number per branch:

```
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Generate build number
      id: buildnumber
      uses: onyxmueller/build-tag-number@v1
      with:
        token: ${{ secrets.github_token }}
        prefix: ${{ github.github.ref_name }}

    - run: |
          write-output $env:build_number
      env:
        build_number: ${{ steps.buildnumber.outputs.build_number }}
      shell: pwsh
```