# Versioning in Github actions without releases or commits

Tags: github, npm, github-actions

I'm trying to setup some kind of versioning pipeline on Github actions. I'm working with a Monorepo with many other project who have their own independent versioning, so I find myself unable to use the releases functionality or pushing my version changes as a commit.

Previously, I worked with Azure pipelines, which have a very useful [`counter` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#counter) whose state is maintained by Azure. It doesn't require committing changes or creating releases, which means I could simply set the version for that specific pipeline with:

```
npm version <value from azure>
```

And the value would automatically change on the next Azure run. On top of that, if either `major` or `minor` values were changed, it would reset the `patch` value to `0` and start the counter again.

Can I do anything similar on Github? I know I can use `${{ github.run_number }}` to get the workflow's number, so I can run:

```
npm version 1.0.${{ github.run_number }}
```

But I'd like my patch version to start back from zero if either `major` or `minor` are changed.

Comment: There's no good answer for this in GitHub Actions at the moment. You'll need to store the version somewhere, be it a tag, release, package, azure blob storage or anything else. A very similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75901913/736079

Comment: We support this via Reliza Hub (3rd party) via get version action - https://github.com/relizaio/reliza-get-version - just create project in Reliza Hub as shown here - https://docs.relizahub.com/get-started/#register-and-log-in and point get version action to it - should give you unique version on each run. Also you can control versioning patch, major, minor if you follow Conventional Commits specification.